# Failed to convert property value of type whenever I upload a photo on spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

The image is a string variable but keep getting error on mismatch input, cannot convert

**Exact error:** Field error in object 'movie' on field 'poster': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@7a56c3d2]; codes [typeMismatch.movie.poster,typeMismatch.poster,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch];

***Service class*** handles changing the name of the image file and storing into local folder

```
public void addMovie(MultipartFile poster, Movie movie ) throws IOException {

        if (!poster.isEmpty()) {
            try {
              // Get the file name
              String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(poster.getOriginalFilename());

              // Save the file to the local project folder
              Path uploadPath = Paths.get("src/main/resources/poster");
              Files.copy(poster.getInputStream(), uploadPath.resolve(fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

              // Save the image details in the database
              movieRepo.save(movie); 

            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        
    }
```

***Controller class***

```
// Add a movie 
    @GetMapping("/movies/add-movie")
    public String addMovie(Model theModel) {
        
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        
        theModel.addAttribute("movie", movie); 
        return "addMovie"; 
    }
    
    //submit the form to save movie 
    @PostMapping("/movies/save-movie")
    public String addMovie(@RequestParam("poster") MultipartFile posterFile, Movie movie, RedirectAttributes ra) throws IOException {
        movieService.addMovie(posterFile, movie);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Movie added successfully!");
        return "redirect:/dashboard/movies";  
    }
```

***addmovie.html*** that hosts the image upload

```
<div class="form-group form-row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Photo</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                       <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png" required class="form-control-file" th:field="*{poster}">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your `Movie` class has a field named `poster` which isn't a `MultipartFile`. Hence it fails.

Comment: The poster field in my Movie class is a string, but I thought I had validations in place to convert it to a String type, so I can store in my DB too 
@M.Deinum

Comment: Validation is validation not conversion, and you defined it as type `file` in the front-end not a regular field. So it has to be a `MultipartFile` in your `Movie` object and then remove the `MultipartFile` object from the controller method so that Spring will do the regular binding.